# Node js ODBC for Windows - alternatives

Tags: node.js, windows, odbc, informix, node-odbc

I need to run node.js on a 32 bit Windows 2008 server AND connect to Informix DB.

I was only able to use node-odbc with node v0.10x and now that version is about to be retired.

Is there any other alternative? I can't install this with node.js v4 or higher.

Comment: I am using `node-odbc` with Node.js v4.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Im facing a similar problem...

Comment: No I am still running the older node release

Answer (score 1):

The current Informix Node JS driver ifx_db is currently based on NodeJS 4x
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ifx_db

The 4x driver has evolved from NodeJS v0.12.x so you could easily extract the code for the version you are looking for. 
The Informix nodejs ifx_db@1.0.0 driver is by using NodeJS v0.12.x. engine; and the snapshot code for this

https://github.com/ifxdb/node-ifx_db/tree/cd150c0d6f6f2d1c2811e4f609dc6c20168d0e1d

Informix Node JS driver is a 64bit, but the same code is compatible with 32 bit platform.
So you may do a local build to create 32bit nodejs driver you are looking for.

Comment: The doc says it will NOT work with Windows platform. Am I wrong there. Unfortunately I only have access to a Windows server to run this program. So either I will have to use it via ODBC or using a native Informix driver.